# Dropdown with for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, dropdown

I have this code and I want to call the cells with a dropdown and I'm stuck here for more than a week; can anyone help me? The code is the problem is how can I call the, the cells are 15 every time and they are called from a database.

```
<?php
$count = 0; 
for ($i = 0; $i < $lessonRows; $i++) {
    $sum = 0;
    require('rowAVG.php');
    if ($average == 100 && $levelPassCounter == 3) {
        $levelPassCounter = 0;
    }
    $average = 0;
    for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
        require('lessonSuccess.php');
        if ($counter == 1) {
            if ($prevCoursePass == 0) {
                ?>
                <button type="submit" class="btn"><?php echo $exercize; echo $counter;?></button>
                <?php
            } elseif ($prevCoursePass == 1) {
                if ($success == 1) {
                    $pass++;
                    $lastSuccess = $success;
                    ?>
                    <button type="submit" style="border-bottom: none;" class="btn" disabled><?php echo $exercize; echo $counter;?></button>
                    <?php
                } else {
                    $lastSuccess = $success;
                    ?>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="p" value="<?php echo $exercize; echo $counter;?>" id="test" onclick="changeName(this)"><?php echo $exercize; echo $counter;?></button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="path" id="path" value="<?php if($_SESSION['audio']==1){ echo 'audio/1.php'; } elseif($_SESSION['textles']==1){ echo 'text/1.php'; } else { echo 'courses/1.php'; }?> ">
                    <input type="hidden" name="lessonID" id="lessonID" value="<?php echo $lessID;?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="courseID" id="courseID" value="<?php echo $courseID;?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="levelID" id="levelID" value="<?php echo $i+1;?>" >
                    <?php
                }
            } 
        } else {
            if ($lastSuccess == 1) {
                if ($success == 1) {
                    $pass++;
                    $lastSuccess = $success;
                    ?>
                    <button type="submit" style="border-bottom: none;" class="btn" disabled><?php echo $exercize; echo "\t"; echo $counter;?></button>
                    <?php
                } else {
                    $lastSuccess = $success;
                    ?>
                    <button type="submit" style="background: #34495e; border-bottom-color: #2c3e50; box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #81CFE0;" class="btn" name="p" value="<?php echo $exercize; echo "\t"; echo $counter;?>" id="test" onclick="changeName(this)"><?php echo $exercize; echo "\t"; echo $counter;?></button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="path" id="path" value="<?php if($_SESSION['audio']==1){ echo 'audio/1.php'; } elseif($_SESSION['textles']==1){ echo 'text/1.php'; } else { echo 'courses/1.php'; }?> ">
                    <input type="hidden" name="lessonID" id="lessonID" value="<?php echo $lessID;?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="courseID" id="courseID" value="<?php echo $courseID;?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="levelID" id="levelID" value="<?php echo $i+1;?>">
                    <?php
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" style="opacity: .5;" disabled><?php echo $exercize; echo "\t"; echo $counter;?></button>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        }
        $lastAVerage = round($average);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please be more clear to your question!

Comment: I dont see a dropdown! I dont see 15 of anything! I dont really see a question

Comment: i am not using the dropdown yet all my  tries failed, the 15 cells are coming via the data base and there are no visible in this code i want to call this, for loop with a dropdown.

Comment: Show what you have done, so we can see what you are trying to do

Comment: <select>
            <?php for($i=0; $i<$lessonRows; $i++): ?>
            <option value="<?php ?>"> <?php 
                for($j=0; $j<3; $j++) echo $exercize;  echo $counter; ?> </option>
             <?php endfor ?>
        </select>    But its tottaly wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

```
           <select>
        <?php  $count=0;
        require ('prevTable2.php');
        $sum=0;
        require ('rowAVG.php');
            for($i=0; $i<$lessonRows; $i++):
                if($average==100 && $levelPassCounter==3){?><?php $levelPassCounter=0; }
                $average=0;
                for ($j=0; $j<3; $j++)
                    require ('lessonSuccess.php');?>
        <option value="<?php ?>"> <?php

            echo $exercize;  echo $counter; ?> </option>
         <?php endfor ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: i tried this one but it doesnt show me all the cells and the count number starts from the 18 and goes 18-21-24-27